# MSc [subject] or MSc in [subject]

Tags: prepositions

If a degree title (e.g., BSc, MSc, PhD, ...) is coupled with the subject (e.g., Physics, Biology, Chemistry, ...), should one use the word "in" in-between (e.g., MSc Physics, or MSc in Physics)? For example, on a CV, what would be the appropriate use?

Comment: I generally see "MSc (BasketWeaving)".

Comment: I imagine this would depend on the locale and context—what you put on a C.V. is not necessarily what you write in a cover letter.

Comment: In India, we say, MA English; M.Sc Chemistry... (.) For introducing one, we use sentences like, He is an MA in English; or an M.Sc in Chemistry...

Comment: Okay, so it's: "Degree: MSc [subject]", but in a sentence, it's more likely to be "an MSc in [subject]". Thanks!